# Most efficient way to store multimedia data in servers

Tags: database, server, architecture, storage, multimedia

When it comes to video and pictures, obviously it is not recommended to store them in relational database. In a purely App and server architecture view, how should we store these data inside our server ?

How do big companies like facebook or youtube store all their data ? 
I know only one way that is to store the file on a server and its path (+ whatever information we want) in a database.

But I feel like this way is old and very tiresome to handle redundancy, caching, load balancing etc..

Is there new architecture model that is becoming popular or easier to implement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "One size fits all" solution.

Many big companies opt for distributed file management system like HDFS/Hadoop for storing media files. Replication/redundancy is easily manageable in this way.

Most small/medium and few large companies use services like Amazon S3. With CloudFront added for caching/CDN.